# Create Zip File on S3 in Laravel 5.1 using S3 bucket files

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I want to create a zip file in my S3 bucket using laravel framework.

Comment: You can upload any file in s3 from your machine in laravel.
You can check https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-AmazonS3-Video or https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 but I'm not sure whether this repository is compatible with 5.1 or not you have to find it.

Comment: check this library it works well for my laravel project. https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper

Comment: Problem is chumper zipper allow me to create zip but doesn't allow to open that zip again and add files into. Anyways i found the solution. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I used the below package to resolved the problem.

```
package jmathai/s3-bucket-stream-zip-php
```

**NOTE:**
**This package has 1 bug it create a zip files but files size are 0kb. To resolve this issue kindly follow the below step.**

After installing this package you need to add the below code in s3BucketStreamZip.php file at line no. 124.

```
fseek($fp,0);
```